# Possible memory leak on the PageEventHandler in iText7 7.1.6

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, fonts, itext, itext7

So I've been testing iText7 trough a 30 day trial license. It's a fantastic library, but I encountered a possible memory leak when using the page event handler. It's not noticeable on documents with 1 or 10 pages, but the process memory skyrockets to 300MBs when making really long documents.
If I take a memory snapshot I can see that the private property documentFonts, inside my instance of the class PdfDocument contains 1000+ fonts, even though I'm just using the default(Helvetica) font!

Before showing you an isolated use-case, I want to specify that I already set immediateFlush to true in the Document constructor.

```cs
using (var fileStream = File.Create($@"C:\Users\my.user\Desktop\test\test0.pdf", 4096, FileOptions.WriteThrough))
using (var writer = new PdfWriter(fileStream))
using (var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer))
using (var doc = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.A4, true))
{
    pdfDocument.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, new NPage());

    int pages = 100000;
    while(pages-- > 0) {
        int paragraphsToAdd = 30;
        while(paragraphsToAdd-- > 0) {
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("text"));
        }
        doc.Add(new AreaBreak());
    }
}
```

The event handler is implemented as such:

```cs
class NPage : IEventHandler
{
    public void HandleEvent(Event @event)
    {
        PdfDocumentEvent eventDoc = (PdfDocumentEvent)@event;
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = eventDoc.GetDocument();
        PdfPage page = eventDoc.GetPage();
        Rectangle pageSize = page.GetPageSize();

        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamBefore(), page.GetResources(), pdfDocument);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDocument, pageSize);

        canvas.Add(new Paragraph("text"));

        canvas.Close();
        pdfCanvas.Release();
    }
}
```

Basically I just want to render something to a canvas everytime a new page is created. But every time this line is executed

```cs
canvas.Add(new Paragraph("text"));
```

the private property *documentFonts* of the pdfDocument object's Count goes up by 1 everytime.

If you change that line and add to the canvas anything that it's not text, the process memory stays around 28MBs and does not go up from there. Am I doing something wrong?

Note: To verify the process memory used I checked VisualStudio's debug window, if that's any useful.

---

#### EDIT 1

I tried to manually set the font in the canvas like so

```cs
canvas.SetFont(pdfDocument.getDefaultFont());
```

and now the process memory stays around 30MBs and does not go up to 200MB like before! My issue is solved but I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: This does look like a bug, I've created an internal Development ticket (DEVSIX-3047) to fix it. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: No problem! I'm happy that I could be helpful :)

Comment: Spent the whole day trying to find the memory leak and indeed setting the canvas font fixed the problem. Thanks!